# Making a global exception handler for Visual Studio 2010 VsPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, vspackage

In previous versions of Visual Studio, there was a single entry point to an extension (more specifically, an addin), the `OnConnect` method. From there it was possible to perform all the Visual Studio operations, such as adding menu items, and setting up a global exception handler, to gracefully handle unhandled exceptions.

In Visual Studio 2010's VsPackage, things work differently - many parts of the application (such as [`IWpfTextView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.aspx)) are composed by MEF and loaded without the explicit control of the package, making handling any exceptions coming from those very difficult.

Without explicitly wrapping all such components in a `try..catch` of their own, how can I efficiently implement a global handler for (non-critical) exceptions in my VsPackage?
Again, the goal is having something like ReSharper's exception dialog, where it can handle global exceptions without crashing the Visual Studio.

Comment: Hm, man. I just wrote a letter to Elisha in which I am asking almost the same question. Duh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have investigated this topic by reading official VsExtensibility forum and according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/2ab45296-de56-49ae-a81a-a2395811df4c) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/6a2d0920-3776-453b-adce-ba5cdf03cf10/) threads there is **no such one place to hook** for catching all exceptions. So typical solution will be to use **try... catches** everywhere.

I suggest to use one of the AOP frameworks like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net) to accomplish this with attributes in order to eliminate tons of crappy duplicated code that's only purpose is to handle unhandled exceptions.